# How to get a list of Apple Time Zones

Tags: macos, timezone

How would I get a listing of all the time zones that Apple has on macOS. For example:

- Pacific Daylight Time
- Central European Standard Time
- etc.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

macOS uses the same TimeZone layout as [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsdwiki.net/index.php/Time_Zones).

Look in `/usr/share/zoneinfo` for each time zone file.

```
ls /usr/share/zoneinfo
Africa          Australia       Etc             MET             WET
America         CET             Europe          MST             posixrules
Antarctica      CST6CDT         Factory         MST7MDT         zone.tab
Arctic          EET             GMT             PST8PDT
Asia            EST             HST             Pacific
Atlantic        EST5EDT         Indian          SystemV
```

Traverse the directories to drill down to the timezone you need.  Eg.  Eastern time would be:

`/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/NewYork`

The file is a C library.  To get the *output* of the file, you can use one of two commands - `zdump` or `file`:

- `zdump /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York`
- `file /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York`

Answer (score 6):

Use this command line in a Terminal window:

```
sudo systemsetup -listtimezones
```

Comment: It's unfortunate that we need to use `sudo` for this.